# Kubernetes offline installation - pause container

Tags: kubernetes

Does anyone know if kubernetes supports an offline installation such as a disconnected network? I downloaded all of the pieces, installed a two node cluster, and when I attempted to run an image from a private registry the "kubectl get events" command displayed that the container could not be started since it could not download gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0. This makes complete sense given the environment but is it possible to configure kubernetes to use a different pause container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [kubelet](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/admin/kubelet.html) has a `--pod-infra-container-image=` flag that you can use to change which infra container is used. If you build your own pause container (starting from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/5520386b180d3ddc4fa7b7dfe6f52642cc0c25f3/build/pause), I'd guess), and upload to your private registry, it should work (although I've not tried it).