# Change default registry for openshift origin

Tags: openshift-origin

Openshift by default will look at docker.io/openshift for its images. In our scenario the openshift cluster does not have access to internet. When I try to start any POD , it tries to request the pause container from docker.io. 
How to override this config and have it look at local registry instead ?

This is similar to below - but I could not find any way to pass this to openshift origin.
[Kubernetes offline installation - pause container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001368/kubernetes-offline-installation-pause-container)

Comment: Ok, this did it for me. Pull the relevant images from docker.io and push to to your.local.registry. Then Update the master-config.yaml and node-config.yaml and restart cluster. It will then pull from local registry                                                                                      imageConfig:
  format: **your.local.registry**/openshift/origin-${component}:${version}
  latest: false

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Please post an answer if you found a solution, not a comment. Comment should only be used to **ask for more information or suggest improvements**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the master-config.yaml and node-config.yaml and restart cluster. 
It will then pull from local registry

```
imageConfig: 
 format: **your.local.registry**/openshift/origin-${component}:${version} latest: false
```

Answer (score 1):

You're also able to define this in your ansible playbook (when using the advanced installation).

```
[OSEv3:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=root
deployment_type=origin
oreg_url=**your.local.registry**/openshift/origin-${component}:${version}

...
```